# How to retrieve get parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

Retrieve HttpGet parameters

I have this method like this

```
        [HttpGet("SendEmails/sendStudentMailIR/{studentID}/{email}/{surID}")]
        public async Task<bool> sendStudentMailIR(string studentID, string email, string surID)
        {
            bool isSent = false;
            ...
            return isSent;
        }
```

Where SendEmails is my controller, sendStudentMailIR is the method
I am using ajax to call it
using this call.

```
        var surID = this.surId();
        var studentID = this.studentID();
        var email = this.collegeStudentEmail();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SendEmails/sendStudentMailIR/" + studentID + "/" + email + "/" + surID,
            data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(this)),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Send");
            }
        });
```

But I never reach the method. What I am missing. Core 3.1 is what i am using.

Comment: You have your controller method marked as "Get" while your `ajax` is trying to do a "Post" Change your `ajax` to `type:'Get'` and also, I don't think you need to pass `data` as the parameters are being passed in the `url`

Comment: Add `[FromQuery]` in the `[HttpGet()]` attribute, I believe that should signal the parameters to be fetched in the query string.

Comment: @janzen they can't be from anywhere else with a GET request `[HttpGet]` as it doesn't have a body (possibly needed if OP changes to `[Route]` so worth mentioning)

Comment: Good to know. Thank you. @freedomn-m

Comment: You should be getting an error (404 or 405) - always add the `error:` callback in your ajax request to see what's happening (or view the network tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep your controller method as it is, an `HttpGet` request, you need to change your `ajax`, please change to the following:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/SendEmails/sendStudentMailIR/" + studentID + "/" + email + "/" + surID,
            //data: JSON.stringify(ko.toJSON(this)), no need to set data as they are passed in the url
            type: 'GET', //You have a controller method of Get not Post
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            cache: false, //don't cache this request
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Send");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception){ //Added error for exception handling

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be `[HttpPost("SendEmails/sendStudentMailIR/{studentID}/{email}/{surID}")]` because you are using type: 'POST' in ajax request

Comment: What if the OP wants the controller method to be `HttpGet`??

Comment: @RyanWilson then they shouldn't use method POST - it's change one or the other, your comment (which I +1'd) suggested change method, this suggests change attribute.  Also, the method is "send emails" so shouldn't be a GET anyway (IMO) as it's not "get"ting data, it's making changes.

Comment: Thanks, totally didnt see this, was looking at the controller never look at my ajax query. so i just change my ajax query to a get.

Comment: @freedomn-m He is getting something, a status on if the emails sent or not.

Comment: @RyanWilson I assumed the "..." was the code that actually sent an email.  POST/PUT still allow a response.

Comment: @Jseb they need to match - change one or the other to whichever you feel is the most appropriate / does the job.